# python control IE download prompt?

Tags: python-2.7, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pamie

i have a script to download some file from web, using browser is Internet Explorer

tried lib selenium, IEC, PAMIE all have same problem "can not control IE download prompt"

even use pywinauto and swapy get browser toolbar..only toolbar

[image]
[image]